What exactly does "interchangeability" in C language refer to?

C11 6.2.5  P28:
A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. 48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.
48) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.

My doubt comes from Note 48. I don't know what "interchangeability" here refers to and I haven't found its official definition either.
I especially want to know what exactly is "interchangeability"?
why only the arguments of functions, the return values of functions and the members of unions are mentioned here as having "interchangeability"?
In other words, why doesn't the standard say : "The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as  members of structs."?
To be honest, I have seen some people give examples of this. But basically they all follow this sentence and then give examples of what they think is "interchangeability", as if you know the result and then make up the result,They didn't explain why these three are special for "interchangeability" and didn't explain what "interchangeability" is from the root first.
Can anyone answer my above doubts? If possible, could you give an appropriate example?
Thank you for your reading.

Notes are not a normative part of the standard—they are statements to help the reader interpret the standard but are not considered part of the official rules of the standard. So you should not expect an official definition for a word used only in a note. It has its plain English meaning: If A and B are interchangeable, that means that wherever A can be used, B can be used with the same effects/consequences, and vice-versa.
This is not a good part of the standard, as it cannot be taken literally. For example, C 2018 6.2.5 28 tells us void * and char * shall have the same representation and alignment requirements, and note 49 tells us this is meant to imply they are interchangeable as return values from functions. But C 2018 6.7 2 imposes a constraint that two declarations of a function must have compatible types, and a violation of this requires a diagnostic message, but two function types are compatible only if their return types are compatible (6.7.6.3 15).
Consider:
void *foo(void);
void *foo(void) { return 0; }

So void * and char * are not actually interchangeable because there will be different behavior with the above code than with the same code with the first void * changed to char * (the compiler will give a diagnostic and typically refuse to compile).
One way that interchangeability does work is that if foo is declared char *foo(void); in one translation unit and defined void *foo(void) { return 0; } in another, then this program should work the same as if void * had been used throughout. But specifying this interchangeability in a note is a crude way to incorporate it into the standard. It seems the committee drafting the standard had something they wanted to say about allowing the use of one of these types for another but did not have a formal way to write it.

So it is your interpretation that the note's "return values of functions" means the same thing as "return types of functions"?  I would not take those to mean the same thing in the specification's normative text.

@JohnBollinger: How could it not mean a type? A value is an abstract mathematical entity, divorce of any representation by bytes in memory. The type is what determines how the value is represented, what the bytes mean. When an argument is passed to a function or a value is returned, it is by way of bytes stored in some location. There is no way to pass an abstract value; it needs a physical manifestation…

… Further, if it were just value, how could there be any opportunity for a char * returned by a function to be interchanged with a void *? If the function is defined to return char *, how could the caller possibly receive a void * instead? If the interchangeability is not referring to some substitution that has given a different declaration for a function than its definition, what has been interchanged with what?

Given the content of the note, the commentary about this provision in the C99 rationale, the wording of the provision itself, and indeed, the issues you raise in this answer, it seems clear to me that the subject of the provision is the reinterpretation of an instance of the repesentation of one type as an instance of the representation of the other type. Not interchangeability in declarations.  I think return values are mentioned in the (non-normative) note mostly because arguments are, and that the mention of union members but not structure members supports that it's about reinterpretation.

@Eric Postpischil: Then how is the "interchangeability" of function arguments manifested? Is it like "When using two arguments with the same representation and alignment requirements respectively, their values should be the same when they are converted to the types of  parameters"?
Could you please give an example of this? Thank you.

@user24723440: It would be the same as the function return type. A function definition with a parameter declared void * would be indistinguishable, as far as calling it from another translation unit, from the same definition with a parameter declared char *.

@Eric Postpischil:Thanks."One way that interchangeability does work is that if foo is declared char *foo(void); in one translation unit and defined void *foo(void) { return 0; } ",Is this an undefined behavior? Because I haven't found the relevant regulations in the standard. Well, I'm not saying that undefined behaviors cannot appear in programs. Maybe some programs really need to be written by taking advantage of this undefined behavior?

@user24723440: Re “Because I haven't found the relevant regulations in the standard”: C 2018 6.5.2.2 9: “If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.” 6.7.6.3 15: “For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types…”

@Eric Postpischil:Your reply has raised new questions for me. Of course, they have nothing to do with this question. I will raise a new one. Thank you for your previous reply first. (I also found the relevant statement: 6.2.7p2: "All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.") Another question related to this one is,If a function is declared and defined in a translation unit and there is a function prototype, is it necessary to convert the arguments of type char* to the parameters of type void*?


Can anyone answer my above doubts? If possible, could you give an appropriate example?

The official C99 rationale document speaks to the intent and historical context of that provision. It observes that types void and void * were added in C89.  Before then, it was conventional to use type char * in the pointer-to-anything role that void * now specifically serves, and standard library functions (among many others) were written accordingly.  The rationale explains that

A pointer to void must have the same representation and alignment as
a pointer to char; the intent of this rule is to allow existing
programs that call library functions such as memcpy and free to
continue to work.

If you're well informed about the behavior surrounding void * then you might be inclined to think that the required automatic conversions between void * and all other object pointer types would take care of this already. Not so.
Bear in mind that function prototypes were also new in C89, and that K&R-style function declarations remain supported even in C17.*  There are no automatic conversions for pointer values passed to a function without an in-scope prototype, so what happens when that legacy code passes a char *, without prototype influenced conversion, to a parameter that has type void *?  Those two types being "interchangeable" for that purpose means that it keeps working as it did before all the char *-to-void * changes in function signatures. Perhaps the return values part was less necessary, but once you demand the same representation on the front end of function calls, it's cleaner to require the same on the back end, too.  And this is exactly what the note in the spec is trying to convey.  Example:
char *memcpy();

int example() {
    char a = 'A';
    char a2;
    memcpy(&a2, &a, sizeof a);
    putchar(a2);
}

The spec's provision is more general, but the note and the rationale are enough to understand the intended meaning.  It's about reinterpreting the bytes of the representation of an object of one of those types as the representation of an object of the other type.  If a program happens to perform such a reinterpretation, in either direction, then there is no loss of fidelity, and both interpretations of the value point to the same object (and for char *, specifically to the first byte of that object).
This is nevertheless a bit fraught.  C specifies that such reinterpretations can be performed through unions, but even C89 declares the behavior undefined when the (promoted) type of one of the arguments to an un-prototyped function has a type that is not compatible with the corresponding parameter's type.  That's exactly what happens if you pass a char * as an argument to memcpy (for example) when no prototype for that function is in scope, and the "same representation" provision doesn't fix it.  The committee could have explicitly provided for that as a special case, but did not.
I think the best way to interpret it is to not.  Do not rely on it in any way.  If you happen to come across legacy code that uses char * where void * is required then fix that code or throw it away, or else just cover your eyes.

why doesn't the standard say : "The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as members of structs."?

Because the committee wanted people to move forward.  Using char * as a pointer to anything was a reasonable accommodation at one time, but the committee wanted to get rid of that.  They put in as small of a nod to backwards compatibility as they thought they could get away with, and that did not include making char * wholly equivalent to or compatible with void *.

*It looks like K&R declarations are going to be absent from C2X, but even then, I anticipate that many compilers will continue to support them for backwards compatibility.

Fortunately, I have studied K&R in depth before, so I fully understand what you mean. That's why in C11, section 6.5.2.2 specifies that when a function has no prototype and its  parameter and arguments are respectively void* and char*, the behavior is defined rather than undefined.

Meanwhile, 6.5.2.2p6 also stipulates that     "one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"     This exceptional case. Coincidentally, I only found the relevant descriptions of "interchangeability" in 6.2.5p9 and 6.2.5p28. This corresponds to these two special cases.This convinces me that your understanding is correct. So for other types with the same representation and alignment requirements, this "interchangeability" is not important, right?

@user24723440, as far as I can determine, the C11 spec associates the word "interchangeable" with representation and alignment only in the two notes you have called out.  I agree that it is meaningful that those correspond to the two exceptions to the requirements for compatible argument and parameter types in the absence of a function prototype, and that there are not any other exceptions.  I see no reason to think that other pairs of incompatible types that are required to have the same representation and alignment requirement enjoy the same kind of exception at function-call boundaries.

There is still one doubt. I saw in C89 that memcpy already has the function prototype void *memcpy (void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);,This will not satisfy the situation of "so what happens when that legacy code passes a char *, without prototype influenced conversion, to a parameter that has type void *",Then why is "the intent of this rule is to allow existing programs that call library functions such as memcpy and free to continue to work."?

@user24723440, C89 was not the first C.  It was just the first standardization of C.  As this answer already observes, void and void * were new in C89.  memcpy() and free() and many other standard library functions (and other libraries' functions) were not.  Prior to C89, it was conventional to use char * as the generic pointer type. The provision in question is primarily for the benefit of legacy code that does that, and perhaps a bit for the benefit of legacy library binaries that do it.

I mean, before C89, char* was used as the generic pointer type, so no matter in the past or now, any type can be a argument of memcpy and memcpy can be called normally. After C89, void* is used as the generic pointer type and memcpy has a function prototype. Now any type can also be an argument of memcpy and it can also be called normally. I can't see why void* needs to have the same representation and alignment requirements as char*.

@user24723440, just because string.h provides a prototype for memcpy or stdlib.h provides a prototype for free does not mean that those prototypes must be visible at the point of a call to one of those functions.  Especially so in C89, which allowed calls to undeclared functions, but even in C17, which (still) allows the program to provide its own (possibly K&R-style) declarations.  And then there's the question (hardly relevant any more) of binary compatibility between objects and libraries built against the older declarations and those built against the newer ones.

If one wants to use these library functions, shouldn't the relevant header files be included? If the relevant header files are included, then why is the function prototype not visible? Do you mean that in C89, library functions can be used directly without including the relevant header files? If so, could you give an example?

@user24723440, again, no, it is not required, in any vesion of C, to obtain function declarations by including a header file.  Not for standard library functions or any other.  In C89, it wasn't necessary even to have declarations at all for many functions, and do recall that the interchangeability language dates to that version.  In any case, even now, where you need function declarations, including for standard library functions, it is allowable to provide your own.  And through C17, those can be K&R style where parameter types permit it.

Forgive my ignorance. "In any case, even now, where you need function declarations, including for standard library functions, it is allowable to provide your own." I have no idea at all that there is such an operation. I have raised this question as a new one. If you have the chance to see it and answer it in detail, I will be very grateful to you.
